# How do I send a JSON object from server to my view using Node/Express and Angular

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I'm trying to build a webapp and I'm stuck at this part: I want to use Contentful to serve my data. Since it's a RESTful service I thought it would be relatively easy to use. They also have a node module, to make my life even easier. Unfortunately, I can't get the data in my view. After hours of googling and on here I've come up with this, but unfortunately it isn't working.

Server:

```
var client = contentful.createClient({
    accessToken: 'token',
    space: 'id',
    secure: true,
    host: 'cdn.contentful.com'
    });

var log = console.log.bind(console);

var movies = client.entries({
    'content_type': '207BVEIb7GcYeCumc2Cmk4'
    }).then(log, log);

app.get('/api/data/movies', function(req, res) {
    res.json(movies);
});
```

JSON:

```
[ { sys: 
 { id: '6nEC5yrZwA0YoikiMeQYky',
   revision: 1,
   type: 'Entry',
   locale: 'en-US',
   contentType: [Object],
   createdAt: Mon Sep 15 2014 22:16:10 GMT+0200 (CEST),
   updatedAt: Mon Sep 15 2014 22:16:10 GMT+0200 (CEST),
   space: [Object] },
fields: { movieTitle: 'Guardians of the Galaxy' } } ]
```

My Controller:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.controller('MainCtrl',['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("/api/data/movies").success(function(data){
    $scope.movieTitle = data.movieTitle;
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));    
    });
 }]);
```

I want to get the movieTitle into my view, but the retrieved data is this:

{"isFulfilled":true,"isRejected":false}

Comment: Is this your _exact_ code? Seems to me as if you're getting the promise object and not your data, and that doesn't make sense with your current code.

Comment: Yeah, this is the exact code. Well, there's obviously more, but this is the code that matters.

Comment: It might be a silly question, but if you put `console.log(movies);` before `res.json(movies)`, what does the console output?

Comment: If I do that, nothing happens... Not in the browser console, nor in the server terminal.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in your server side code. This example code:

```
var movies = client.entries({
  'content_type': '207BVEIb7GcYeCumc2Cmk4'
}).then(log, log);
```

Is assigning a *Promise* to the `movies` variable. Unfortunately, it's a promise for the result of the `log` function, so you should change it to this:

```
var movies = client.entries({
  'content_type': '207BVEIb7GcYeCumc2Cmk4'
});
```

The next problem is that you are never calling `then` on the promise to get it's resolved value. The simplest way to deal with this (assuming you never want the movie list to be refreshed) is to just call `then` inside your request handler:

```
app.get('/api/data/movies', function(req, res, next) {
  movies.then(res.json, next);
});
```

This sets up `res.json` to run if the movies promise resolves successfully, and `next` to handle any errors.

If you want the list of movies to be re-retrieved on each request, then you could move the `client.entries` call into your request handler as well:

```
app.get('/api/data/movies', function(req, res, next) {
  client.entries({
    'content_type': '207BVEIb7GcYeCumc2Cmk4'
  }).then(res.json, next);
});
```

One final note: it's also possible (and encouraged) to perform these requests directly from the browser, so you wouldn't even need the express app to proxy requests.